# Setting different activityitems for for different different services in UIActivityViewController ios

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

For Sharing content I'm using `UIActivityViewController` For this I have subclassed `UIActivityProvider`
for providing different content For different services.

I'm returning array For `ActivityItems` in ActivityProvider but array is getting nil.
I want to share string and URL.

//my subclass code is

```
-@implementation ActivityProvider
- (id) activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController
      itemForActivityType:(NSString *)activityType
{

if ( [activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToTwitter] )
{
    NSArray * activityItems = @[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Some initial text."], [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
    return activityItems;
}
if ( [activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToFacebook] )
    return @"This is a facebook post!";
if ( [activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypeMessage] )
    return @"SMS message text";
if ( [activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypeMail] )
    return @"Email text here!";
if ( [activityType isEqualToString:@"it.albertopasca.myApp"] )
    return @"OpenMyapp custom text";
return nil;
}

- (id) activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController { return @""; }
```

Is there any way to set subject and body for mail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide a subject for your email by implementing

```
- (NSString *)activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController subjectForActivityType:(NSString *)activityType;
```

in a class that conforms to the `UIActivityItemSource` protocol. See [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActivityItemSource_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIActivityItemSource/activityViewController%3asubjectForActivityType%3a) for more information.